# Define nested extension containers in Gradle

Tags: gradle

I'm at the point in implementing my first Gradle plugin where I need to define nested extension objects.  The User Guide doesn't yet cover this.  There have been several questions about this in the past year or so, but I can't assemble a solution from what I've read.

This is what I believe I'd like the user to be able to do:

```groovy
yang {
  yangFilesRootDir      "src/main/resources/yang"
  inspectDependencies   true

  generators {
      generator { // line 25
          generatorClassName "org.opendaylight.yangtools.maven.sal.api.gen.plugin.CodeGeneratorImpl"
          outputDir "build/gen1"
      }
      generator {
          generatorClassName "org.opendaylight.yangtools.yang.unified.doc.generator.maven.DocumentationGeneratorImpl"
          outputDir "build/gen2"
      }
  }
}
```

My first random stab at this looks like this, and I'm sure this isn't even close yet:

```groovy
public void apply(Project project) {
    project.plugins.apply(JavaPlugin)
    YangExtension       yang    = project.extensions.create(YANG_EXT, YangExtension)
    project.yang.extensions.generators  = 
        project.container(CodeGeneratorsContainer) {
            println it
        }
```

Here are my extension classes:

```groovy
class YangExtension {
    CodeGeneratorsContainer     generators
    String                      yangFilesRootDir
    String[]                    excludeFiles
    boolean                     inspectDependencies
    String                      yangFilesConfiguration
    String                      generatorsConfiguration
}

public class CodeGeneratorsContainer {
    Collection<CodeGenerator>   generators
}

class CodeGenerator {
    String  generatorClassName
    File    outputBaseDir
    Map     additionalConfiguration
}
```

When I run this right now, it fails with the following:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'name' on null object
at org.gradle.api.internal.DynamicPropertyNamer.determineName(DynamicPropertyNamer.groovy:36)
at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection.add(DefaultNamedDomainObjectCollection.java:70)
at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractNamedDomainObjectContainer.create(AbstractNamedDomainObjectContainer.java:58)
at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractNamedDomainObjectContainer.create(AbstractNamedDomainObjectContainer.java:52)
at org.gradle.api.internal.NamedDomainObjectContainerConfigureDelegate._configure(NamedDomainObjectContainerConfigureDelegate.java:39)
at org.gradle.api.internal.ConfigureDelegate.invokeMethod(ConfigureDelegate.java:73)
at build_2a353qtggi869feteaqu2qgc3$_run_closure1_closure3.doCall(....\workspace2\YangUsingProject\build.gradle:25)
```

And I've marked line 25 in the build script, if that matters.

**Update**:

After integrating the solution, this is a summary of the required setup.

Sample structure in a "build.gradle" file:

```groovy
yang {
    yangFilesRootDir        "src/main/resources/yang"
    //excludeFiles          "target.yang"
    inspectDependencies true

    generator {
        generatorClassName  = "org.opendaylight.yangtools.maven.sal.api.gen.plugin.CodeGeneratorImpl"
        outputDir           = "build/gen1"
    }
    generator {
        generatorClassName  = "org.opendaylight.yangtools.yang.unified.doc.generator.maven.DocumentationGeneratorImpl"
        outputDir               = "build/gen2"
    }
}
```

Plugin "apply" method:

```groovy
public void apply(Project project) {
    project.plugins.apply(JavaPlugin)
    YangExtension       yang    = project.extensions.create(YANG_EXT, YangExtension, project)
    YangGenerateTask    task    = project.task(YANG_GENERATE_TASK, type: YangGenerateTask)
    project.afterEvaluate {
        task.init(project, yang)
    }
}
```

Extension class:

```groovy
class YangExtension {
    private Project project

    Collection<CodeGenerator>   generators
    String                      yangFilesRootDir
    String[]                    excludeFiles
    boolean                     inspectDependencies
    String                      yangFilesConfiguration
    String                      generatorsConfiguration

    YangExtension(Project project) {
        this.project    = project
    }

    CodeGenerator generator(Closure closure) {
        def generator = project.configure(new CodeGenerator(), closure)
        generators.add(generator)
        return generator
    }
}
```

And finally, the CodeGenerator POGO:

```groovy
class CodeGenerator {
    String  generatorClassName
    String  outputDir
    Map     additionalConfiguration
}
```

Comment: Do you have any reference how to convert this to Java?
I'm having difficulty passing the project object to the extension.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The error is caused by the fact that `Project.container()` attempts to create a [`NamedDomainObjectContainer`](https://gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/NamedDomainObjectContainer.html). This special type of collection requires to the collection type to specify a `name` property. An common example is `sourceSets`, where each item has a unique name (main, test, etc). The DSL would then look like:

```groovy
generators {
   codeGenerator { 
      generatorClassName "org.opendaylight.yangtools.maven.sal.api.gen.plugin.CodeGeneratorImpl"
      outputDir "build/gen1"
   }
   docGenerator {
      generatorClassName "org.opendaylight.yangtools.yang.unified.doc.generator.maven.DocumentationGeneratorImpl"
      outputDir "build/gen2"
   }
}
```

If it doesn't make sense to give each generator a name, then your best bet is simply to define a method on your extension that configures a new instance of your `Generator` object. The catch here, is since **you** are instantiating the generator if won't have all the fancy decorations that Gradle would do (such as setter methods). If you want capability, you'll have to manually define those methods on the `Generator` class.

**Update:**

In order to leverage `Project.container()` and create a `NamedDomainObjectContainer`, the container type must have a property called `name` and a public constructor which takes a `String` argument for the name. The value of this property is being whatever name I use when I initially configure the object. For example:

```groovy
sourceSets {
    integTest {
        srcDir 'src/integTest'
    }
}
```

The code above **creates** and **configures** a new `SourceSet` with the name "integTest" and adds it to the container. You could leverage this with your "generators" by simply adding that property. You would also want to modify your extension class as well to make the `generators` property of type `NamedDomainObjectContainer<CodeGenerator>` and there is no need for the additional `CodeGeneratorsContainer` class.

```groovy
class YangExtension {
    NamedDomainObjectContainer<CodeGenerator>  generators
    String                      yangFilesRootDir
    String[]                    excludeFiles
    boolean                     inspectDependencies
    String                      yangFilesConfiguration
    String                      generatorsConfiguration
    
    YangExtension(Project project) {
        this.generators = project.container(CodeGenerator)
    }
}
```

```groovy
class CodeGenerator {
    String  generatorClassName
    File    outputBaseDir
    Map     additionalConfiguration
    private String name
    
    CodeGenerator(String name) {
        this.name = name
    }
    
    String getName() {
        return this.name
    }
}
```

**Update 2:**

In case it doesn't make sense to have named object in your DSL, you could simply provide a method on your extension that configures a new `CodeGenerator` and adds it to a collection.

```groovy
class YangExtension {
    Collection<CodeGenerator> generators = new ArrayList<>()
    private Project project

    YangExtension(Project project) {
        this.project = project
    }

    CodeGenerator generator(Closure closure) {
        def generator = project.configure(new CodeGenerator(), closure)
        generators.add(generator)
        return generator
    }
}
```

Your new DSL would then not have a `generators` block. It would simply look like this:

```groovy
yang {
    generator { 
        generatorClassName = "org.opendaylight.yangtools.maven.sal.api.gen.plugin.CodeGeneratorImpl"
        outputDir = "build/gen1"
    }
    generator {
        generatorClassName = "org.opendaylight.yangtools.yang.unified.doc.generator.maven.DocumentationGeneratorImpl"
        outputDir = "build/gen2"
    }
}
```

Comment: Woosh.  No comprende. Each generator could use the value of "generatorClassName" as it's "name", if that's what you mean. I have no idea how to define these extension objects.  Defining the base one is simple, if it doesn't have nested objects, but once you take that one step over the line, there seems to be no information on how to do that.

Comment: Take a look at my early [flyway](https://github.com/ben-manes/gradle-flyway-plugin) plugin that uses containers to support multi-db migrations. This was removed when contributed as the official plugin due to the project owner not understanding Gradle or the use-case.

Comment: Ok, then perhaps the "NamedDomainObjectContainer" isn't what I need. I'll need to specify multiple generators, but except for the difference in the "generatorClassName" property, they aren't conceptually different from each other. The main task will iterate through the generators and each will generate code from the same set of inputs.  What I see in the referenced "flyway" code has similarities to what I'm trying to do. I'll see if I can get somewhere with that approach.

Comment: I believe the approach I outlined above, and the one used in the flyway plugin mentioned by Ben are the same. The "name" the user gives each generator is arbitrary. This convention just happens to be a requirement for `NamedDomainObjectContainer`. However, you get all sorts of benefits, such as live collection methods and an expressive DSL. In your task you would simply do something like `yang.generators.all { generator -> /* code to process each generator */ }`.

Comment: With this, would the user still define a "generators" block, containing one or more "generator" blocks, each with a "generatorClassName" and "outputDir" property?  From what you've described, it seems like the code wouldn't care if they called each one "generator" or gave different names for each one. Correct?

Comment: They would have to have unique names. If you were to use the name "generator" for them all, it would result in only creating a single `CodeGenerator`, and all subsequent blocks would simply reconfigure the same object.

Comment: For this situation, it just doesn't make any sense to require the user to give them unique names. I understand the NamedDomainObjectContainer requires this, but it doesn't make sense for my needs. How can I allow the user to define a "list" structure?  I suppose I don't need the "generator" container, if I can define something like an array of rows with named fields.

Comment: Ok.  Looks good.  I'll add an update to the original question showing the setup.